# How to filter identical subnetworks between two graphs? [networkx]

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying create two graphs with the identical networks between them removed.

Graph 1:

[image: graph1]

Graph 2:

[image: graph2]

To demonstrate what I want to do:

1. In red, I highlight a network in both graphs that has several similar nodes (e.g.  B Arg 511, B Asp 513 ...). However, graph 2 has more nodes connected and different edges that connect them.
2. In green, I highlight identical networks.

Essentially, I'd like to keep the different networks and exclude identical ones.

I tried using networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.difference() but it doesn't work since they don't have identical node sets.

A potential solution might be to make sets of sets of the node networks for each graph and take the difference. Then try  to graph that instead?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for a list of all largest subgraphs that belong to the both parent graphs. Assuming you have no prior info regarding what kind of subgraph you are looking for, I see no better way to solve it except to.. try all possible subgraphs. It works nice theoretically however absolutely impossible on practice due to combinatorial explosion. Problems becomes much harder if you gonna look for isomorphic subgraphs — those which have the same structure but made of possible different sets of vertices and/or edges.

Otherwise you have to extend your question with what else you know about subgraph you gonna look for and it may or may not help to find a better way to solve the problem.